# Node.js - JSON error Unexpected Token

Tags: json, node.js, actionscript-3

I'm trying to send some data into a Node server from AS3 through JSON. I have written this JSON for test purposes and sent this data to node (**AS3**):

```
var usrJson = [{"id": "21", "name": "testName"}];
usrJson = JSON.stringify(usrJson);
socket.send(usrJson);
```

The object reaches the node server, because when I console.log it, it is ok, but when i console.log a property of this object with this (**JS**):

```
function onData(d){

    strData = d.toString();

    console.log(strData);     // returns [{"id": "21", "name": "testName"}]

    json = JSON.parse(strData);
    console.log(json);           // Returns the error below

}
```

The error shown:

```
[{"id": "21", "name": "testName"}]
                                  ^
Syntax Error: Unexpected Token
```

I tried verifying my JSON with JsonLint and it was ok. Maybe I'm missing something in the js file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have trailing garbage?  If I take that object, then `stringify` it, then `.toString` it, then `JSON.parse` it I get no error. The string you're posting is valid JSON...

Comment: Try posting just [{"id":1}], then make a simple check in the JS: `console.log(strData == "[{\"id\":1}]");` if not - then the problem is withing your chars.

Answer (score 1):

```
function removeBadChars(str) {
        var alfavit1 = "abcdefjhijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFJHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_'";
        var alfavit2 = ':,."_0123456789[{}]';
        var resStr = '';

        for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
            var fchar = str.substr(i,1);
            if ( alfavit1.indexOf(fchar) >=0 || alfavit2.indexOf(fchar) >=0 ) {
                resStr = resStr + fchar;
            }
        }

        return resStr;
    }
```

before JSON.parse use this function